# DNS Propogation issue/DNS record not found

Tags: domain-name-system

Trying to get test site working again after a record deletion and need help understanding what could be causing the issue.

```
dig @8.8.8.8 +short yeandel.com
```

returns nothing, yet there are two A records for www.yeandel.com and yeandel.com - both resolve to an IP on which is a running bitnami stack.

whois.net confirms the name servers shown also in the dig below.
These NS's are in the Route53 Hosted Zones record and in the domain's DNS server entries.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> yeandel.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8234
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yeandel.com.           IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yeandel.com.        3600    IN  NS  ns-1221.awsdns-24.org.
yeandel.com.        3600    IN  NS  ns-188.awsdns-23.com.
yeandel.com.        3600    IN  NS  ns-833.awsdns-40.net.
yeandel.com.        3600    IN  NS  ns-1687.awsdns-18.co.uk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-188.awsdns-23.com.   2371    IN  A   205.251.192.188
ns-833.awsdns-40.net.   2371    IN  A   205.251.195.65
ns-1221.awsdns-24.org.  2371    IN  A   205.251.196.197
ns-1687.awsdns-18.co.uk. 2371   IN  A   205.251.198.151

;; Query time: 71 msec
;; SERVER: 103.86.96.100#53(103.86.96.100)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 27 10:43:03 BST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 241
```

When I test the record set in the aws console Route53 reports it to be valid but there are no records globally.
For completion, the TTL on the NS entries was 172800 (more than 2 days ago now) and I have reduced it until this is solved.
This was a domain that was GandI.net that I moved to AWS and had been working for a long time.

Many thanks

Kevin

Comment: Those Route53 nameservers respond that there are no records for `yeandel.com. IN A` or `www.yeandel.com. IN A` when queried directly (eg `dig @ns-1221.awsdns-24.org yeandel.com +norec`). Are you sure that the records are actually there and that this is the same hosted zone that you added the records to?

Comment: Thanks Håkan, inspired me to do dig in a different direction, I found the correct ns's from an old archive. They are wrong and if I dig the old list then I get the IP response expected.